# Need help making JS functions more dynamic

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is use the JS functions for additional input fields in the form. For instance, I want to have a LastName and LastNameLabel, etc. I am hoping I can adjust the functions in some way to find pairs Aaa and AaaLabel so that every field can have the same effect. My code is below. Thanks!

Update: I am now just trying to get the 'Original Value' to show the name of the element ID with a space between a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter. For example, if the element ID is LastName, I want the innerHTML to be "Last Name". Thanks for all your help!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function LabelOnClick(el) { var associatedFieldId = el.getAttribute('for');
                              if (associatedFieldId)
                                 document.getElementById(associatedFieldId).focus();
                            }
  function FieldOnFocus(el) { document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').className='FieldFocus';
                            }
  function FieldOnKeyPress(el) { if (event.keyCode!=9 && event.keyCode!=8) { document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').innerHTML='';
                                                                           }
                               }
  function FieldOnKeyDown(el) { el.style.width = Math.max(30,el.value.length*10)+'px';
                            }

  function FieldOnKeyUp(el) { el.value=el.value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+el.value.substring(1,el.value.length);
                              if (el.value=='') document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').innerHTML='Original Value';

                            }
  function FieldOnBlur(el) { if (el.value=='') { document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').className='FieldBlur';
                                                 document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').innerHTML='Original Value';
                                               }
                           }
</script>

<style>
  .InputField { border: 1px dotted lightgray;
                border-bottom:1px solid black;
                min-width: 30px;
                padding: 5px;
                font-family:tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
  }
  .FieldBlur { color: gray;
               position: absolute;
               padding: 6px;
               padding-left: 8px;
               padding-top: 8px;
               font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
               font-size: 14px;
  }
  .FieldFocus { color: lightgray;
                position: absolute;
                padding: 6px;
                padding-left: 8px;
                padding-top: 8px;
                font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
  }
  .FieldInput { color: black;
                position: absolute;
                padding: 6px;
                padding-left: 8px;
                padding-top: 8px;
                font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
```

```
<label id="FirstNameLabel" for="FirstName" class="FieldBlur"
       onclick="LabelOnClick(this)">First Name
</label>

<input id="FirstName" class="InputField" type="text" name="FirstName" maxlength="25"
       onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)"
       onkeypress="FieldOnKeyPress(this)"
       onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)"
       onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)"
       onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>

</body>
```

Comment: The way you've already coded `FieldOnKeyUp()` to pass a reference to the clicked element through is probably all you need to do on the other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, ignoring the fact that inline event handlers are generally frowned upon these days, try something like the following, in which the `onclick` and `onfocus` in your HTML pass `this` through to the associated functions such that those functions have a reference to the element that the event was triggered on so that they can figure out what the related field or label is:

```
<script>

function LabelOnClick(el) {
   var associatedFieldId = el.getAttribute("for");
   if (associatedFieldId)
      document.getElementById(associatedFieldId).focus();
}

function FieldOnFocus(el) {
   document.getElementById(el.id + "Label").className='FieldFocus';
}

</script>

<label id="FirstNameLabel" for="FirstName" class="FieldBlur"
       onclick="LabelOnClick(this)">First Name  </label>

<input id="FirstName" ... onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" ... />
```

I'll leave doing something similar for the other events as an exercise for the reader...

**EDIT to match your updated question:**

If this:

```
document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').innerHTML='Original Value';
```

is the part you're talking about where you want to replace `'Original Value'` with the elements ID with spaces added then at that point `el.id` holds "LastName" so if you use a regex like in the following line you should get "Last Name":

```
document.getElementById(el.id + 'Label').innerHTML
                      = el.id.replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but what about the innerHTML references? How can I make those adapt? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand why you're changing the innerHTML of the label as the user types, but if your question is how to take an unknown string in the format "FirstName" (such as you could retrieve from the ID like I've already shown you above) and insert a space so that you get "First Name" you could use something like the following regex replace which puts a space before any uppercase letter preceded by a non-uppercase letter: `"FieldNameOfDoomABC".replace(/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2")` (will return "Field Name Of Doom ABC"). If that's not the issue please be much more specific.

Comment: That can work if I can set the innerHTML equal to the spaced-out version of the element's ID. However, I am not having luck with that.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to do exactly? Also, the following line in your `FieldOnKeyPress()` function won't work: `document.getElementById('FirstNameLabel')='FieldInput';` - what's that meant to do? You need to specify a property just before the `=` sign, e.g., `document.getElementById('FirstNameLabel').innerHTML='FieldInput';`

Comment: I'm going to post my most current in place of the old code in the initial post and I will clarify my remaining question there. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are a JavaScript magician! So, I have one more question. Can the script that spaces out the ID between lowercase and uppercase letters ignore everything until the second capital letter in the ID. For instance, instead of the ID "FirstName", I want to make it "ApplicantFirstName" or "CoapplicantFirstName", but I want the Original Value to simply be "First Name". Thanks again.

Comment: Run this replace after the existing one: `.replace(/^[^ ]+ /g, "");` - it should (untested) delete everything from the beginning of the string up to and including the first space. You should read up on [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4815/discussion-between-mike-and-nnnnnn)